# AngularJS Dateformatting

Tags: angularjs, date, format

I get a date in this format:

```
2015-02-19 00:00:00
```

Now I need to format this date to

```
19-02-2015
```

I tried:

```
sc.documents.datestring = $filter("date")('2015-02-19 00:00:00', 'dd-MM-yyyy');
```

But that didn't work, anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First argument should be Date object, not a string. All  yon need to do is:

```
sc.documents.datestring = $filter("date")(new Date('2015-02-19 00:00:00'), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

yes when ever you want to display date using some format using angular filter we need to use

```
$filter('date').(date, format, timezone);
```

format ,like as above only...
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date